# How do you organize your Backbone files?

Tags: backbone.js, organization

I'm looking to implement backbone into a large web project with multiple "apps" that will be using it and I'm trying to figure out a good way to organize my files. The two I've come up with so far are:

```
js
+- models
|  +- search
|  |  +- result.js
|  |  +- ...
|  +- cart
|  |  +- item.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
+- collections
|  +- search
|  |  +- results.js
|  |  +- ...
|  +- cart
|  |  +- items.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
+- views
|  +- search
|  |  +- resultRow.js
|  |  +- ...
|  +- cart
|  |  +- itemRow.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
+- routers
|  +- search
|  +- cart
|  ...
```

And

```
js
+- search
|  +- models
|  |  +- result.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
|  +- collections
|  |  +- results.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
|  +- views
|  |  +- resultRow.js
|  |  +- ...
+- cart
|  +- models
|  |  +- item.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
|  +- collections
|  |  +- items.js
|  |  +- ...
|  ...
|  +- views
|  |  +- itemRow.js
|  |  +- ...
+- routers
|  +- search
|  +- cart
|  ...
```

I'm leaning towards the latter as it has clearer lines between sections of the website and keeps the apps together but our current structure of the back-end framework is much more like the former.

Comment: Put models & collections in one folder, call them result.js and result_collection.js.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

i would go with a modified version of the second... basically, drop the folders for m, v and c in each of your site sections. there's really no need to separate these into subfolders when the file names and class names will already reflect what they are.

```
js
+- search
|  +- result.js
|  +- results.js
|  +- resultRow.js
|  +- ...
+- cart
|  +- item.js
|  +- items.js
|  +- itemRow.js
|  +- ...
+- routers
|  +- search
|  +- cart
|  ...
```

looking at this layout, i still know that "item" is a model, "items" is a collection and "itemRow" is a view, because that's the convention that you have set up. adding the extra layer of folder names just adds complexity and adds no value, in my opinion.

also - (you probably know this, but in case others reading this post don't...) be sure to use something like require.js to consolidate / minify all of your js into a single file before deploying to your production environments. keeping code organized like this is great for development and debugging purposes. but when it comes time for a production system to use the code, having it split out into multiple files causes significant delays for the end-user. require.js solves this problem by providing an easy way to have both - organized files during dev work, and a single minified file for production.

Comment: Yea we use a custom server side bundler that uses .htaccess rules to pass all js file requests through it which then bundles the files together and their dependencies then decides whether to minify depending on the environment. It's cached server side and client side until a new push generates a new cache key (on dev this cache key is overriden to be the current time.)

Comment: What other alternatives to require js do you recommend? just for packing all files into a single file (optionally minified)